# How can you define an objects properties as variables without knowing their names?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I am defining a series of variables like so:

```js
let test = {one:1, two:2, three:3}
let {one, two, three} = test
```

This would define the variables `one`, `two`, and `three` with the corresponding values in the `test` variable. Now say I want to define all of the values in `test` as variables but I don't know the elements inside it. How could I do that?

So far I've tried using an array in it like

```js
let {["one", "two", "three"]} = test
```

but I get errors

```
let {["one", "two", "three"]} = test
           ^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
```

Then I tried using the spread operator first like

```js
let {...["one", "two", "three"]} = test
```

But that didn't work either and had the same error.

I have absolutely no idea where to continue from here.

Comment: You cannot define variables with dynamic names; the concept doesn't really make sense. The definition of a variable with `var`, `let`, or `const` is the binding of a name into the relevant scope. If you don't know the name, there's nothing to bind, and there would be no way to make use of the variable anyway in code in that scope.

Comment: @Pointy I understand how this can be a niche use case but for me I am attempting to load all of the variables from a `require()` statement into variables in my current scope but since I update the keys in the json frequently, I don't want to also have to update the script each time. Am I looking at this use case wrong and is there a different solution?

Comment: Thank you for the close! I couldn't find this anywhere!

Comment: How would you make use of any of the variables in subsequent code?

Comment: as you would with any variable. That question to my understanding seems very vague, I would use them as objects to store information?

Comment: @Asian I don't think that something like this will solve your problem, because even if you manage to put all the keys from json in js variables dynamically, you will have to use them in the code by name - so you really don't achieve anything by doing this.

Comment: @NoyGafni yes, I will be using the variables in the script but this is more for convinience's sake

Comment: You are not understanding the question. If you have a block of code with variable names that you don't know in advance, how would you (for example) write a statement to add two of the variables together and store the result in a third variable?

Comment: @Pointy exactly, what I am saying is that if you use the "dynamic" variables by name in the code it self - you will need to change all the usages of them when you change your keys in the json. so to define them dynamically will not help you at all because you need to change the code no matter what

Comment: @Pointy Going through the duplicated post, I see people talking about using `eval`, I am not doing any user-input or front-end work so could you potentially direct me to an example of using `eval`? Sorry for taking your time up

Comment: @Nationalism there are almost certainly better ways of solving your implementation issues than using `eval()`.